# Notepad++: Adding tabs in between lines

Tags: formatting, notepad++, indentation

This question, if anything, more has to do with resolving my OCD when working on these text files, but I feel like a picture helps describe better what I intend to do than anything I can describe:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDmi5.png

What I'm looking to accomplish is lining up the values (with tabs, not spaces) all on the same column (in this case, column 53), but I don't know how to go about it effectively.

Rushing out to work at the moment so if I need to provide more information to help, let me know and I'll post back when I'm home. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, you have the following text:

`aaa         aaa
    a`

You can hit `tab` after `a` on the second line, and after a couple of hits, it should get you to the column in which `aaa` begins in the row above.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a setting somewhere? I'll peak around for it, thanks :D. While this is really helpful to know, I still am looking for a better method if possible, because there are around 100+ files, some with over 1000 lines each to go through.

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit: if you want to structure lots of code, you could look into [regular expressions](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)